# mysql query to find record filtering on the datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which the following data structure is used:

```
col1    col2    timestamp
value1  value11 2014-27-04 03:05:25
value2  value22 2014-28-04 03:05:25
value3  value33 2014-27-04 04:05:25
```

Now I want to retrieve the rows which timestamp is greater than equal to 03:05:25 hours but that should be today's data...not the previous days data.

To avail this I have used the following query but this

```
select * from tab1 where time(timestamp) > '03:05:25';
```

But this returns all the data of previous days also. Any help on this is will be very helpful.

Comment: `where timestamp > = concat(curdate(),' ','03:05:25')` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty...thanks dude...perhaps a silly question I might have asked

Comment: No question is silly as long as it makes sense, and your question is pretty valid question.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIME(timestamp)>01:01:01 AND DATE(timestamp) = DATE(NOW())
```

Wouldnt that fit your need?

Mel_T's will work too. Either use concat to bring it together or split it into 2 filters (time and date).

Answer (score 0):

To select all rows of the same day but later than 03:05:25 you can do this:

```
select * from tab1 where timestamp > CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 03:05:25');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    `timestamp` AS `timestamp`,
    date(`timestamp`) AS `date`,
    time(`timestamp`) AS `time`
from `timestamps`
where date(`timestamp`) = date(now()) AND time(`timestamp`) >= '03:05:25'
;
```